# Cant get a valid regex to work in nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am trying to use following nodejs function to check an existence of specific kind of url in my string. I checked this regex separately and it looks good, but get me an error in node.

```
var checkforURL = function(data) {
   var re = /((?:https?://)?www\.example\.com\/tp\/\S+\d+)/g/;
   return re.test(data);
}
```

this should return true for following cases

- http://www.exmaple.com/tp/123
- www.exmaple.com/tp/abc/123
- https://www.exmaple.com/tp/123

etc etc

when i try to run the code i get following compilation error
  var re = /((?:https?://)?www.example.com/tp/\S+\d+)/g/;
                         ^

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
>       at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:906:3

I need this parenthesis, they enclose https?:// to make sure it can exist 0 or 1 time, not sure why nodejs keeps throwing an error, any idea?

Comment: You need to escape the forward slashes in `https?://` and also you need to remove the last `/` after g.

Comment: is that `example` or `exmaple`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slashes in `https?://` and also you need to remove the last `/` after `g`. Change the string `example` to `exmaple`,

```
var re = /((?:https?:\/\/)?www\.exmaple\.com\/tp\/\S+\d+)/g;
```

The above regex should match the following urls,

```
http://www.exmaple.com/tp/123
www.exmaple.com/tp/abc/123
https://www.exmaple.com/tp/123
```

To match `example` links,

```
var re = /((?:https?:\/\/)?www\.example\.com\/tp\/\S+\d+)/g;
```

If you want to match both example and exmaple links then give `m` and `a` inside a character class.

```
((?:https?:\/\/)?www\.ex[ma][ma]ple\.com\/tp\/\S+\d+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE4fI1/6)

Comment: That 'exmaple' killed me